# The program 'xxx' has exited with code -55 (0xffffffc9)

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When pressing 'Start' to debug my application (currenly in WPF app, it happens with Console Apps too) the blue bar at the bottom changes to orange and says 'Loading symbols for mscorlib.dll' which then gives me this in the output window:

```
'xxx' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[20892] xxx' has exited with code -55 (0xffffffc9).
```

However when I spam press 'Start' over and over again it eventually comes in a debugging sate and opens an actual window.

Configuration Manager is on Debug & Any CPU.
Loading the .exe from the debug folder works just fine, using CTRL + F5 also works just fine.

Uninstalled all my Visual Studio versions and only installed 2017 Community back on my system and it still happens.

Searching for error code -55 doesn't give me anything either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'd have to wait until the crappy anti-malware product you use finished scanning the file.  They notoriously don't work well on a programmer's machine that makes executable files appear from seemingly nowhere.  Don't wait, get rid of it.  The one included with your OS doesn't hassle you like this.

Comment: @HansPassant If you post that as an answer I'll accept it. As indeed it was Malwarebytes, uninstalled it straight away.

Comment: Just share what you discovered in your own post and mark it as the answer.  That programmers need to keep this product off their machine is pretty useful information.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem was removing **[Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/)** from my machine. As pointed out by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant).

Details:
Be sure to *restart* your machine after uninstalling the software.
I tested VS2015 Community and that ran just fine with the software installed.